# meaning of "should this be the case"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "should this be the case" ?

Can you support your answer with examples?

Thanks

Comment: *Should this be* is the (relatively formal) "subjunctive" version of ***if this is***. And *to be the case* is a relatively formal way of saying *to be true, to come to pass*. Putting it all together, your example phrase is just a long-winded formal alternative to ***If [this is] so***.

Comment: This phrase has multiple meanings depending on context. The two primary meanings are as a question ("Should this be the case?") and as a qualifier ("We will have to act, should this be the case.") Which version is your question about?

Answer (score 1):

*Should X be the case, [then] Y* generally means *if X happens or becomes/is discovered true, Y*.

Usually the "then" is understood and not written/spoken unless emphasis is needed.

Y will often be a direct or indirect request or call for (in)action of some sort.

The immediate thing that comes to mind with this expression is an expression of a contingency or "backup plan" of some sort.

> I don't expect to be gone more than a day, but should this be the case, try to get back in touch with me.
>
> That customer is getting belligerent.  I don't think I will have problems escorting him out, but should this be the case, stay right behind me.
>
> I don't think anything will happen to me, but should this be the case, please let Michael know.
>
> I don't think any issues will happen, but should this be the case, be prepared to come up here and help me.
>
> The weather doesn't look like it's going to be bad, but should this end up being the case, it's not smart to go.
>
> Take a look in the jar over there.  I don't think it's rotten, but should that be the case, throw it away.